# edited html mail returns result with ascii/weird characters

Tags: html

i have this problem with this html file which i am editting. it is for an edm to be sent via email.
i have been editing the contents all this while until recently i tried to change the background from #FAFAFA to #666666, and on the preview shows "ï»¿ " on the very first line. the problem does not exist on the original, appears only after i edit, and remains after i undo the change.
done some googling and below are my guesses;
- encoding problem ; could have been if i inserted special or language characters, but only replaced #FAFAFA to #666666
- style classes ; i'm using style in the html. was okay in the original file until i did that little change.
- version ; could only think of this but wasnt sure if it really affects. the original file was done up in a win7 dreamweaver5.5 and currently editing with a win8 notepad.

any lovelies out there to help? i need to send this out today.....

Answer (score 0):

You should set the character encoding of your document to UTF-8 using the [meta charset attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: hi joren, i have the below codes which i believe should be what you are suggesting?
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
anything else?

Comment: hi joren, isnt it the same thing? but anyway, i tried adding it in, but it still doesnt work.